# S3 CopyObjectRequest between regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy some objects between 2 S3 buckets that are in different regions.

I have this:

```
      static void PutToDestination(string filename)
      {
        var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);
        var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsS3RegionNameSource));

        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest();
        request.SourceKey = filename;
        request.DestinationKey = filename;
        request.SourceBucket = awsS3BucketNameSource;
        request.DestinationBucket = awsS3BucketNameDest;

        try
        { 
        CopyObjectResponse response = client.CopyObject(request);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
      }
```

I get "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

There doesn't seem to be a way to set separate endpoints for source and destination.

Is there a different method I should look at?

Thanks

Comment: You should be specifying the destination bucket region in the client constructor, not the source bucket.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2212 (Provide destination region when building the S3:Client). Worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

I think, if you don't specify the region explicitly, then Copy between cross region should work.

[See documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html)

However, the accelaration will not work and copy will be

> COPY=GET+PUT

Here is explanation excerpt from documentation that says-

> Important
>
> Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration does not support cross-region copies.

In your code, you are specifying the region like below.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .build();
```

Instead initialize S3client without region like below.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()).build();
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. You will get an exception {
  "errorType": "AmazonS3Exception",
  "errorMessage": "The eu-central-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.",